# Use of Primitive `byte` increased space occupied when compared to Primitive `int`

Tags: java, memory-management

I have a sample program for which I'm testing the memory occupied. I don't know where I'm going wrong or I'm implementing something wrong. But when I use `byte` instead of `int`, memory occupied by JVM is increased. Below are two class files:

***Class Test1:***

```
public class Test1 {
    public Test1 node1, node2;
    DATATYPE a, b; // DATATYPE is Primitive `int` or Primitive `byte`
}
```

***Class Test:***

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println(getMemory());

        Test1 root = new Test1();
        Test1 currNode = root;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            currNode.node1 = new Test1();
            currNode.a = 10;
            currNode.b = 10;
            currNode.node2 = currNode;
            currNode = new Test1();
        }

        System.out.println(getMemory());
    }

public static String getMemory()
    {
        HashMap<String, Double> hm = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        hm.put("\nTotal Memory ", (double) runtime.totalMemory()/(1024*1024));
        hm.put("\nFree Memory ", (double) runtime.freeMemory()/(1024*1024));
        hm.put("\nUsedup Memory ", (double) (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory())/(1024*1024));
        return hm.toString();
    }
}
```

***Output1 when DATATYPE = int:***

```
{
    Free Memory = 966.1398086547852, 
    Total Memory = 981.5, 
    Usedup Memory = 15.360191345214844}
{
    Free Memory = 869.7226409912109, 
    Total Memory = 981.5, 
    Usedup Memory = 111.77735900878906
}
```

***Output1 when DATATYPE = byte:***

```
{
    Free Memory = 966.1398086547852, 
    Total Memory = 981.5, 
    Usedup Memory = 15.360191345214844
}
{
    Free Memory = 765.0790710449219, 
    Total Memory = 981.5, 
    Usedup Memory = 216.42092895507812
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Byte is a boxed primitive which requires more memory than primitives such as int, double, etc.

Object references such as boxed primitives (e.g. Byte, Integer, Double) have additional overhead such as a Class reference.

Therefore using byte instead of Byte should resolve your issue.

Comment: Additionally, try using the primitive `byte` and I think the memory usage will be substantially lower than the usage with `int`

Comment: That is strange. The primitives byte and int are both stored in a 32 bit cell so I would have thought that the memory consumption should be the same.

Comment: @DermotBlair Even I was expecting memory used up when used byte should be less than equal to memory occupied when I use int. I don't know what could be the reason for this.. I'm stuck in the middle of nowhere..

Comment: I have done some looking around and all the answers online I found seem to suggest that using byte should consume less, or at most the same, memory as int.

Comment: @Prasanth The text of your question says you're using `Byte.` Check it. You mistyped it here, you could have mistyped it in the code. It's the most plausible explanation.

Comment: My bad. I typed it wrong here. I changed it in the question. But my problem is not solved.